# Error when setting Firebase Service Account with typescript

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

According to Firebase Console, in order to setup a service account I need to include the following snippet:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://project.firebaseio.com"
});
```

I've put the json in the same folder as my index.ts:

```
// src/index.ts
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
var serviceAccount = require('./firebaseServiceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://project.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Nevertheless when I upload the firebase functions I get this error:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

SyntaxError: /home/woowapdabug/projects/    Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

SyntaxError: /home/woowapdabug/projects/server/functions/lib/firebaseServiceAccountKey.json: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 2364
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:671:27)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/woowapdabug/projects/server/functions/lib/index.js:5:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)server/functions/lib/firebaseServiceAccountKey.json: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 2364
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:671:27)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/woowapdabug/projects/server/functions/lib/index.js:5:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
```

Comment: It looks like your `firebaseServiceAccountKey.json` is invalid. Check it in a text editor, to see if it is JSON. If not, download a new `firebaseServiceAccountKey.json` from the console.

Comment: The one I'm using is the one that I've downloaded from the console

Comment: Me also having the same issue ..